# navigating to same page in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, navigation, windows-phone-8

In my WP8 app, i have situation where i have to navigate from one page to another and afterwards i need to reload the same page for some reasons.

MainPage.xaml --> Page1.xaml --> Page1.xaml --> Page1.xaml

When user press the backkey should go back to "MainPage.xaml" page.

I tried using the `NavigationService.navigate()` for navigation, some reason i couldn't able to reload the page. If i pass any unique query strings (eg: Guid) with navigation url, i am able to reload the page. But, when i press back button - it never goes back to Mainpage.xaml page.

Is there any best way to achieve this?

Comment: can you pass a `#` sign in the PostBack URL..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass in a query string every time you reload the page (such as your random GUID). On your `OnNavigatedTo` method check if the GUID query string exists. If it does exist, you know that you don't want this page on the `Navigation Stack` because it's the reloaded version, so you can remove it by calling [NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.removebackentry%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string guid = string.Empty;
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("guid", out guid))
    {
       //guid exists therefore it's a reload, so delete the last entry
       //from the navigation stack
       if(NavigationService.CanGoBack)
          NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.removebackentry.aspx) method to remove last navigation stack entry.

You can also remove all elements from navigation history:

```
while(service.CanGoBack)
    service.RemoveBackEntry();
```

and then add the one you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?" + DateTime.Now.Ticks, UriKind.Relative));
```

You can use it under a control to navigate to same page

Answer (score 0):

Because I couldn't find any Windows 10 (Universal apps UWP UAP) questions about this, and this one seems to be top result on google search to reload a page, here is a solution:

```
NavigationService.Refresh();
```

I'm using [Template 10](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki) on my app, so I don't know if it matters here. The lib encapsulates NavigationService on its own INavigationService