# Windows Phone navigate to new instance of same page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In my Windows Phone app, I need to navigate from a page to a new instance of the same page.

How can I achieve this?

If I navigate as follows:-

Page1 -> Page2 -> Page1

It creates a new instance of Page1.

I want to create a new instance as follows:-

page1 -> page1

I tried

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

on Page1.xaml - it doesn't navigate.

Comment: First thought: create `Page3.xaml` with automatic redirect to `Page1.xaml` and use it as proxy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [navigating to same page in windows phone 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751251/navigating-to-same-page-in-windows-phone-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i pass any unique query strings (eg: id) with navigation url, i am able to reload the page as follows -

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?ID="+ a.MyID, UriKind.Relative));
a.MyID++;
```

Answer (score 5):

Pass a parameter in the page Uri, for example:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(String.Format("/Page1.xaml?id={0}", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()), UriKind.Relative));
```

Then, if you don't want to keep the previous instances in the navigation stack, you can remove the previous instance calling `RemoveBackEntry` method of `NavigationService`:

```
NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
```

Comment: was writing my answer while you posted yours
Thank you anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

Very simple. You can achieve it by using below code. Don't forget to mark it as an Answer.

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml?reload=true", UriKind.Relative));
```