# Refresh current page in wp8,

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-phone-8

I'm try to refresh current page but not able to do this. Basically I used user control and inherit to another user control. Button click event is working properly. But not refresh the page.

```
Page = (Application.Current.RootVisual as Frame).Content as Page;
string u = Convert.ToString(Page.NavigationService.CurrentSource);
Page.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(u, UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 1):

The Problem here is you can't use navigation in `UserControl`, It must be from `Page`.
So, in your user control create an event handler like this..

```
public event EventHandler Refresh;
```

Now, in your page make its `Handle` as..

```
MyUserControl.Refresh += UserControl_Refresh;

void MyUserControl_Refresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //refresh logic here
}
```

Then in your `UserControl` invoke this `Event` where ever required as

```
Refresh.Invoke(this, null);
```

And it will work.

Answer (score 0):

just enter your desired page there on any event you wish it will refresh the page

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/pagetorefresh.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: not working getting error object reference becz it's place in usercontrol

Comment: try to put this code outside usercontrol on any simple button click event and check if it is working or not

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing the `BackStack`?

```
NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
```

[How to reload a Windows phone application page without creating a new copy in the memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23127788/)

[navigating to same page in windows phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751251/)

Comment: I'm try refresh current page

Answer (score 0):

When you want to Navigate to a Page from UserControl, you have to do like this

```
 (Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(new Uri("/ProjectName;component/Pages/SignatureCapturePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

And when you want to Navigate to a new instance of a page(in which you are residing), you need to append a new GUID

```
(Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(new Uri("/ProjectName;component/Pages/SignatureCapturePage.xaml?id="+Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), UriKind.Relative));
```

But your ultimate purpose it to refresh the page and not to navigate to a new page, so you can either trigger a event in the page from your UserControl or go for DataBinding.

DataBinding is the best approach and you can get notified using INotifyPropertyChanged when some changes happens with the Usercontrol. See [DataBinding for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/cc278072(v=vs.105).aspx)